# Best way to represent a training set to split with

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, artificial-intelligence

A training set is made off a set of samples and a set of labels one for each sample. In my case a sample is a vector while a label is a scalar. To deal with this I use Numpy. Consider this example:

```
samples = np.array([[1,0],[0.2,0.5], [0.3,0.8]])
labels = np.array([1,0,0])
```

Now I have to split the training set in two partitions shuffling the elements. This fact raise a problem: I loose the correspondence with the labels. How can I solve this?

As the performance is critical in my project I prefer not to construct a permutation vector, I am looking for a way to bind the labels with the samples. By now my solution is to use as label the last column of the samples array like:

```
samples_and_labels = np.array([[1,0,0],[0.2,0.5,0], [0.3,0.8,1]])
```

Is this the fastest solution for my case? Or are there any better? For instance creating pairs?

Comment: You're sure that splitting your data is the bottleneck? Not, maybe, training the model?

Answer (score 1):

The mixing of indices with float datatypes makes me uneasy. When you say split the training set, is this completely random? If so I would go with the random permutation vector - I don't think your solution is any faster (even without my data type reservations) because you're still allocating memory when creating your samples_and_labels array.

You could do something like (assuming `len(samples)` is even for simplicity of illustration):

```
# set n to len(samples)/2
ind = np.hstack((np.ones(n, dtype=np.bool), np.zeros(n, dtype=np.bool)))
# modifies in-place, no memory allocation
np.random.shuffle(ind)
```

and then you can do

```
samples_left, samples_right = samples[ind], samples[ind == False]
labels_left, labels_right = labels[ind], labels[ind == False]
```

and call

```
np.random.shuffle(ind)
```

whenever you need a new split

Answer (score 0):

Without numpy, maybe it's not so fast. You can try import "_random" intead of just "random" for better shuffling performance.

```
import random

samples = [[1,0],[0.2,0.5], [0.3,0.8]]
labels = [1,0,0]

print(samples, '\n', labels)

z = list(zip(samples, labels))
random.shuffle(z)

samples, labels = zip(*z)

print(samples, '\n', labels)
```